# Where did jetty plugin for 1.3.7 go?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a legacy grails 1.3.7 app and can't find jetty-1.2-SNAPSHOT plugin for it.  Anyone know where I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to have SNAPSHOT dependencies in your app, because those often get cleaned out. Judging by the [commit history](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-jetty/commit/c56cd2d970f3ad60b77df7f4e8273897b2dc86c3) of the plugin, it looks like 1.2-SNAPSHOT turned into 2.0.0.

If you go to http://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/browserepo.html, and look under plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/jetty it looks like there is a version 1.1 and 2.0.0 (and some others). Maybe one of those will work for you.

If you really do need 1.2-SNAPSHOT, you'll probably need to check out that specific commit and run the plugin inline. How are you using the Jetty plugin, if you're just using it to run the wars, I would imagine that you would be able to use a newer version without a problem.